# Why some types exist in a metadata file?

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm porting an ASP website project to a web application project. I came across a namespace and type that I can not find defined anywhere. I checked them in the working old website, they always refer to a file in a temp location whenever I go to definition [F12]. The location is [C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Temp\MetadataAsSource\e98d1328e8484b79bd026794a3eeb63e\536d6ba4484547879b395d3105ab2bf5

```
    #region Assembly App_Web_wuctoolbarcustom.ascx.eeb48aa3.alvsygha,    Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    // C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0bfb755\_shadow\bd9578ae\25500\App_Web_wuctoolbarcustom.ascx.eeb48aa3.alvsygha.dll
    #endregion

    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using JDQ.Controls;

    namespace ASP
    {
        [CompilerGlobalScope]
        public class jdqcontrols_wuctoolbarcustom_ascx : ToolbarCustom
        {
            [DebuggerNonUserCode]
            public jdqcontrols_wuctoolbarcustom_ascx();

            [DebuggerNonUserCode]
            protected override void FrameworkInitialize();
        }
    }
```

The new web application doesn't compile because of the type or namespace ASP couldn't be found, while the older website compiles successfully even if I delete the metadata files in the temp location. I am guessing this file is generated somehow, I was wondering how can I do the same thing for the web application?

Comment: Is one of your pages referencing a user control by path? ie `<%@ Register Src="~/path/to/control.acsx" TagName="MyTag" TagPrefix="uc1" %>`

Comment: Yes there is. But it is not a page it is another usercontrol. But the same path exists in both projects.

Comment: Looks like auto-generated code for "wuctoolbarcustom.ascx"...

Comment: When you reference by source, especially in that way, you need to make sure that the relative pathing remains consistent. ASPX/ASCX pages are compiled at run-time unless special measures are taken, and if that file does not exist relatively to the new project you've created, you'll get the kind of error you're describing. This is something I've observed in legacy ASP/ASP.NET Webforms projects that has broken functionality unexpectedly. I would recommend referencing the DLL that owns the control you want to nest locally, and registering it through it's fully qualified type name, not the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Apparently the way they used to call a User Control in a Web Site project was using the type ASP.namespace_control_ascx and that type was generated at runtime since websites are compiled at runtime, but web applications are pre-compiled and that's why that type couldn't be found. A simple reference to the user control by the class name (like you would any other type) was the way to go (which couldn't be done in a web site).

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue, Although this might be correct way, after doing many trail error, finally i changed the name space, it compiled new dll and everything is fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34854822)